# How can I texture a GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I have got a few GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP primitives which are drawn like so:

```
glNewList(heightmapDisplayList, GL_COMPILE);
for (int z = 0; z < data.length - 1; z++) {
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    for (int x = 0; x < data[z].length; x++) {
        glVertex3f(x, data[z][x], z);
        glVertex3f(x, data[z + 1][x], z + 1);   
    }
    glEnd();
}
glEndList();
```

How would I texture this? I easily know how to texture things such as a `GL_QUADS`, but I do not know where to put the `glTexCoord2f()` calls with a triangle strip (and the iteration and such).

I use lwjgl, so an answer in java would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the texture coordinates for each of the vertices of the primitive: for each call to glVertex3f, there should be a matching call to glTexCoord2f. Regarding the actual values of the texture coordinates, it depends on what you want to achieve. A simple way would be to derive the 2D texture coordinates (s, t) from the indices used for the triangle strips. Here is an example implementing this:

```
glNewList(heightmapDisplayList, GL_COMPILE);
for (int z = 0; z < data.length - 1; z++) {
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    // The t texture coordinate for z and z + 1
    float t0 = (float)z / (data.length - 1); // t0 in [0,1]
    float t1 = (float)(z + 1) / (data.length - 1); // t1 in [0,1]
    for (int x = 0; x < data[z].length; x++) {
        // The s texture coordinate for x
        float s = (float)x / (data[z].length - 1); // s in [0, 1]
        glTexCoord2f(s, t0);
        glVertex3f(x, data[z][x], z);
        glTexCoord2f(s, t1); 
        glVertex3f(x, data[z + 1][x], z + 1);
    }
    glEnd();
}
glEndList();
```

Comment: It didn't work. Instead, it came out with a white output. Also, nothing else rendered. Am I missing something?
http://gyazo.com/054f1d005e0922a1c4d95a7290445c9a
Even my (Green) ship is blue! And I am only seeing a small part of the terrain. 

Without your code for the textured terrain, it normally looks like this: http://i.gyazo.com/757549850eaebf8123c24afb24ffdac2.png

Here is the pastebinned code: http://pastebin.com/JVRxPM9k

Would be great if you could help!

Comment: The order of the calls is wrong here. The `glTexCoord2f()` calls need to be **before** the corresponding `glVertex3f()` calls.

Comment: Besides the mistake what @RetoKoradi pointed out, the last bound texture in the code snippet is lookupTexture not textureID.